# mongoid querying problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, mongoid

I have a Three documents, here is a sample with fields not shown

```
class College
  include Mongoid::Document
  references_many :students,:stored_as => :array, :inverse_of => :colleges
end

class Student
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :college, :inverse_of => :students
  embeds_one :mark
end

class Mark
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :student, :inverse_of => :mark
end
```

Now when I perform the search like this in console

```
@college = College.find('4cb2a6457adf3500dd000089').students.where('mark.total' => '100').first.name
```

gives me nil as there is no any students with total marks == 100

provided that college exists but the same code raises error in my actual code as

```
ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for Array:0x00000107441a30
```

Any ideas why this is happening?  OR have i done some thing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: 9 questions and 0 accepted. If you accept the answers to your questions it's likely you will receive more answers in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
references_many :students,:stored_as => :array
```

means that the value returned by the students call here

```
College.find('4cb2a6457adf3500dd000089').students
```

is an array, not a chainable Criteria.
You need to split the query into two statements.

Comment: thanks for the response, but i still need to query on the students array though. Please give me some idea how to query on the array of students obj so that i can find the students with marks = 100. And it would be helpful if i know what stored_at => :array does? Is it the performance issue or some thing else.

Comment: I kinda have the same problem. what exactly is the purpose of stored_as? cause using it will cause other problems

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one query.  Something like:
College.find('4cb2a6457adf3500dd000089').where("students.mark.total' => '100').first